# Can Haskell Typeclasses be Partially Implemented?

Tags: haskell, types, functor, applicative

I want to make a pair type to represent modular arithmetic.  I made its constructor

```
{- LANGUAGE GADTs -}
data Zn e where
    Zn :: Integer -> Integer -> Zn Integer
```

because I would like to be able to `fmap` over it and all the things.
So if I try to make it a `Functor` instance

```
instance Functor Zn where
    fmap f (Zn s n) = Zn s $ mod (f n) s
```

I get `Could not deduce: b ~ Integer from the context: a ~ Integer`.  Of course it cannot deduce this because this data type does not have a meaningful notion of `fmap :: (a -> b) -> Zn a -> Zn b` for all `a` and `b`, but it does whenever `a` and `b` are such that one could actually construct `Zn` instances from them (ie `Integer`).  I also tried having the `Zn` constructor and all methods require `Integral e` but I get a similar problem.  In that case, `s` has type `a` so constructing a `Zn` with it and `f n :: b` fails.  In the second case I could convert `s` from `a` to `Integer` and then to `b` but this is clunky.  The whole thing is a bit clunky.  I'm just doing it because I want to be able to implement `Functor` and `Applicative` to perform `mod` after mapping a function so I can just implement `+` as `liftA2 (+)` and so on.  The modulus `s` should be part of the type but dependent types are not practical in Haskell as far as I know.

Is it possible to have a type with kind `* -> *` implement `Functor` only for some arguments?

Comment: If you're trying to make that type into a number, I think your `s` needs to be at type level. Otherwise, someone could give you `Zn 3 2 + Zn 8 7`, and what would you return then?

Comment: It would be ideal to have `s` in the type, but I think having it be a runtime error is better than using the `Nat` trick to encode numbers in types.  I would put the modulus in the type if Haskell had more direct support for dependent types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`MonoFunctor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.15.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFunctor). It's just like `Functor`, but works with a fixed inner type instead of being parametrically polymorphic. Here's how you'd implement it for your type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.MonoTraversable

data Zn = Zn Integer Integer

type instance Element Zn = Integer

instance MonoFunctor Zn where
    omap f (Zn s n) = Zn s $ mod (f n) s
```

However, be warned that such an instance isn't exactly lawful. You may be better off just making a `modMap` function or something, to avoid people making bad assumptions about how it will work.

Comment: I think this is at least morally lawful. As far as I can see, the only law which is broken is `omap id = id` which fails e.g. for `Zn 2 10` because `10` should have been `0`. If we consider the values up to equivalence, I think it should be lawful.

Comment: @chi It breaks the other law too. ``let f x = x `mod` 8; g x = x * 6; m = Zn 9 4``. Now `omap f (omap g m)` is 6, but `omap (f . g) m` is 0.

Comment: True. The problem if that your `f` does not respect the equivalence. One needs to consider as morphisms only those `f`s such that `mod s x = mod s y ==> mod s (f x) = mod s (f y)`. So it is a mono-functor, I guess, but only on a suitable subcategory (which can not be enforced using types.)

Comment: @chi I feel like it's REALLY stretching "morally lawful" to make that argument though.

Comment: I agree. That's too much.

Comment: Interestingly the MonoTraversable library does not include `MonoApplicative` so one could add that class, but for now I'm just using `modMap` and `modLift2`.  Applicative is problematic anyway because `pure` doesn't know the modulus.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer for now because it solves the problem in this case and I don't think Haskell allows "partial" implementation of typeclasses.